# css background repeat is not working

Tags: css

I have a css class called navigation which will hold some link and when i'll add some extra link it will go from left to right and then again it'll come to bottom of the LHS. i use background-repeat: repeat-y; and height:auto; but the image is not repeating instead of a white background is coming. I'm working on IE8. the css codes are given below:

```
#navigation {
    background: url(../images/custom/lite/navigation_bg.gif);
    border-top: 7px solid #455660;
    height: auto;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

#navigation ul,
#add-page {
    float: left;
}

#navigation a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    font: 14px/56px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

 #navigation .selected a {
    color:#000
}

 #navigation .selected a {
    font-size: large;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@reuben, you given `float` in your `ul` so you have clear it `#navigation`

like this:

```
#navigation {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

may that's help you

Comment: but i'm calling it from a div i.e <div id="navigation">

Comment: @ Sandip .. the image is rendering some 4 0r 5 pixels from the left hand side only... after adding that line.

Comment: can you show your html code for better understanding & give feedback as early as possible.

Comment: its a velocity macro file...

<div id="navigation" class="sort-pages modify-pages">
 <ul>
  #foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)
   #if ($nav_item.isSelected())
    #set ($nav_item_class = "selected")
   #else
    #set ($nav_item_class = "")
   #end

   <li class="$nav_item_class">
    <a href="$nav_item.getURL()" $nav_item.getTarget()><span>$nav_item.getName()</span></a>

    #if ($nav_item.hasChildren())
     <ul class="child-menu">
      #foreach ($nav_child in $nav_item.getChildren())
       <li>
        <a href="$nav_child.getURL()" $nav_child.getTarget()>$nav_child.getName()</a>.....

Comment: @sandip its coming fine if i do it like background-repeat:repeat; instead of background-repeat:repea-y; with visibility:hidden

Comment: please put in your post not in comment box :)

Answer (score 0):

What does your HTML look like? You say you have a class called navigation but your selector syntax is that of an ID.

For your CSS to work as shown here, you should have something like

```
<div id="navigation">...</div>
```

Comment: I don't suppose this would be an answer.

Comment: Yes. its for an id. and am calling it from a vm file where the code is like : <div id="navigation" class="">

Answer (score 0):

change your css to the below:

```
.navigation {
    background: url(../images/custom/lite/navigation_bg.gif);
    border-top: 7px solid #455660;
    height: auto;
    background-repeat:repeat-y; }

.navigation ul,
#add-page {
    float: left; }

.navigation a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    font: 14px/56px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    text-decoration: none; }

.navigation a:hover {
    color: #000; }

 .navigation .selected a {
    color:#000 }

 .navigation .selected a {
    font-size: large;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
```